# violentmonkey greasemonkey есть ли хранилище?

Tags: javascript

Скажите есть ли у этих расширений какое то общее хранилище?
Я знаю есть localstore, но оно только в пределах страницы работает, я же делаю скрипт, чтобы у него была общая база значений.
нашел вот это https://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual:API
Но у меня что то не работает, пишет что нет такого объекта GM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в `violentmonkey` нет самого объекта GM

Тут нужно используйте так:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name demo
// @namespace test
// @include http://www.example.com/
// @grant GM_getValue
// @grant GM_setValue
// ==/UserScript==

GM_setValue('x', 999);
var res = GM_getValue('x');
```

Comment: подробней про setValue тут https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.setValue

Comment: да спс разобрался